# See date on button click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The below code not showing the expected output of current date and time

```
class Mydate extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      date:new Date(),
      showMessage: false
    }
    this.show=this.show.bind(this);
  }
  show(){
    this.setState({showMessage: true});
    return this.state.date;  
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Hello World!!</h2>
         {this.state.showMessage && <p>{this.state.date}</p>}
        <button onClick={this.show}>show Date</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

why show() doesnt work here.Can you please help me to know where is the issue

Answer (score 2):

As i checked `this.state.date` is an js Date object, when it's printing in the document its tying to convert it to string to make sure its a valid children in jsx, and gets fails. use something as below

```
<p>{this.state.date.toString()}</p>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e358bk)

Answer (score 0):

currently, the date object is being rendered as an object within the `<p>` tag. Objects cannot be passed as "children" to jsx tags.

A minimal fix would be to convert the date to string using toString() method when displaying the date within the `<p>` tag.

```
   render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Hello World!!</h2>
         {this.state.showMessage && <p>{this.state.date.toString()}</p>} 
        <button onClick={this.show}>show Date</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-smoke-vtiyf?file=/src/App.js:511-522

I hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: @g is it correct if i simply return this.state.date.toString() in show() without using  conditional rendering. I cant see the  output

Comment: @RayErd No. the return value of show() is not used by the onClick event. You do not need to have a return in show function.

When this.state.showMessage is false, JS will not check the second part of the && conditional render statement, therefore not rendering the JSX.

in your use case, calling show() will set showMessage in this.state to true, causing react to rerender the component, and on the next render evaluate the second part of the && which simply returns JSX and displays your date string.